# c++ thermometer with classes error messages

Tags: c++

I know the thermometer problems have been done to death but I thought I would give this a shot.

I keep getting the error messages "use of undeclared identifier 'converterc'"  and "use of undeclared identifier 'converterf'".  Any ideas?

Spike

```
 #include <iostream>
#include "converters.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int degree;
    int weehoo;

    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t Enter the temperature : ";
    cin>>degree;
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t If the temperature is in Celsius enter 0, if Farenheit enter 1 :";
    cin>>weehoo;

    if (weehoo==0)
    {
        cout<<"\n\n\t\tThe temperature in Farenheit is "<<converterc(degree,weehoo)<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\n\t\tThe temperature in Celsius is "<<converterf(degree,weehoo)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
#ifndef __again_converters_h
#define __again_converters_h
#endif
#pragma once

class Thermometer
{
private:
float degreeC;   //celcius
float degreeF;   //farenheit

public:
void setCelcius (float c) {degreeC=c;}
void setFarenheit (float f) {degreeF=f;}
float getCelcius (void){return degreeC;}
float getFarenheit (void){return degreeF;}
Thermometer  (float degree=0,float f=0, float c=0,float outtemp=0);
float converterc(int degree,int weehoo);
float converterf(int degree,int weehoo);
};
```

converters.cpp file
     #include "converters.h"

```
 float Thermometer::converterf(int degree,int weehoo)
{
degreeC=((degree-32) * (.5556));
return degreeC ;

}
float Thermometer::converterc(int degree,int weehoo)
{
degreeF=((1.8)*degree)+32;
return degreeF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`converterc` and `converterf` are member function of the class `Thermometer` but you're calling them without a `Thermometer` instance.

How about creating a `Thermometer` instance in your main?

```
Thermometer tm;
tm.converterc(degree, weehoo);
```

Answer (score 0):

`converterc` and `converterf` are functions in your class. This means they are there to be called on an **object being an instance of this class** or class derived from this.

```
class Thermometer
{
private:
float degreeC;   //celcius
float degreeF;   //farenheit
//...
public:
float converterc(int degree,int weehoo);
float converterf(int degree,int weehoo);
};

    int degree = 1;
    int weehoo = 2;
    Thermometer t; //initialize it properly if this is needed before calling functions
    float f = t.converterc(degree,weehooo);
```

using these functions in the way you did this:

```
float f = converterc(degree,weehooo);
```

is possible as:

```
float f = Thermometer::converterc(degree,weehooo);
```

but then they have to be **static** what means they don't have `this` pointer and are common to whole class (still you can call them using an instance of class but it is not necessary):

```
class Thermometer
{
private:
float degreeC;   //celcius
float degreeF;   //farenheit
//...
public:
static float converterc(int degree,int weehoo);
static float converterf(int degree,int weehoo);
};
```